# What is the bottom thumb swiper bar called in iOS 14?

Tags: ios

What do you call the black line at very bottom of the screen in the following picture? It is used to activate ["App Switcher"](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph1a1f981ad/ios).

[image]

Image taken from https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/toolbars/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known as the "Home Indicator".